# Partial sort using sortedArrayUsingDescriptors

Tags: ios, sorting

I would like to do a partial sort of an array before sorting the complete array. The following Will return an array sorted on “sortOrder”

```
[folders sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES]]
```

The array will look like this: [x, a, z, w, y]

but I would like to sort on “name” in ascending order when “sortOrder” is equal to zero first.

So the final array would look like this: [a, x, z, w, y]

Does anyone have a idea on how to do this?

```
"folders": [
     {
        "sortOrder": 0,
        "name": "x",
     },
     {
        "sortOrder": 0,
        "name": "a",
     },
     {
        "sortOrder": 1,
        "name": "z",
     },
     {
        "sortOrder": 3,
        "name": "y",
     },
     {
        "sortOrder": 2,
        "name": "w",
     }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in two sort descriptors, one for "sortOrder" and the second for "name":

```
NSArray *descriptors = @[
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES],
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES],
];

NSArray *sortedArray = [folders sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

With this setup, any two items with the same sort order will then be sorted by name.